# Routes match error upgrading from 2.3 to 5.2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am upgrading an app from Rails 2.3 to Rails 5.2.3 and ran into an error with match in routes.rb

Error I get is:
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/"):

actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:65:in `call'

routes.rb file is:

```
  FullcalendarAssets::Application.routes.draw do
    resource :calendar, :only => [:show]
    resources :events
    resources :emails
    resources :conversations
    resources :users
    root :to => 'homeowners#login'
    match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

match method is deprecated in rails 5.0 or above, the reason is to encourage people to use only `GET` and `POST`.

reference: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/5964

you can either use `GET` and `POST` or edit the `MATCH` route to be like this:-

`match ':controller/:action/:id', via: [:get, :post]`